# delay is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, method-chaining

I keep getting an error like this:

```
$("div.valid_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show().delay is not a function
[Break On This Error] $(...elay(10000).hide("slow", function() {
```

in my code:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.errorsExist) {
        $('div.valid_box').hide();
        $("div.error_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show(); 
    } else {
        $('div.error_box').hide();
        $("div.valid_box").html(data.message).css("margin-left", "145px").css("width", "520px").show().delay(10000).hide("slow", function() {
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        });    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably loading older version of jQuery somewhere that overwrites the new version. Search for this mistake and remove loading the old jQuery.